# jQuery/Javascript Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked, prop

i want do something like this with a checkBox. if the user clicks on the checkbox, it should change its state (checked -> unchecked and vv. ).

my code:

```
$('#checkBoxStandard').change(function() {
    clickedFormBoxen('standard');
});


function clickedFormBoxen(active){
if(active == 'standard'){

    if( $('#checkBoxStandard').is(":checked")){

        $('#checkBoxStandard').prop("checked", false);

    }else{

        $('#checkBoxStandard').prop("checked", true);
    }

    console.log('ac: '+$('#checkBoxStandard').is(':checked'));
}
```

Unfortunately, the checkbox will not be unchecked again. The fist time, the checkbox is getting checked, but if i click on it again, nothing happens, it's still checked.

I wish to use this code so i can change the state of the checkbox by function call and not just by user interaction.

Please help me and sorry for my english^^

Comment: as far as i can see, you revert the change of user action that causes the change event to fire. how do you set the initial state of the  checkbox ?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#checkBoxStandard').removeAttr("checked");
```

Comment: manipulationg the `checked` attribute is [officially discouraged](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this? ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PiranhaGreg/wjLnM/))

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">Hey,check me!</label>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var respond = true;

function manualCheck(state)
{
    respond = false;
    $('#checkbox').prop("checked", state);
}

$('#checkbox').change(function ()
{
    if (!respond)
    {
        respond = true;
        return;
    }

    // Your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i've mentionend in my comment to your question, with your function `clickedFormBoxen` you effectively revert the effect of a user interaction on the checkbox element. Thus it seems that you have to call the change handler from a click handler on your checkbox element (i've streamlined the code a bit):

```
function clickedFormBoxen(active) {
    if (active == 'standard') {
        $('#checkBoxStandard').prop("checked", !($('#checkBoxStandard').prop("checked")));
    }
}

$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#checkBoxStandard').change( function(e) {
        clickedFormBoxen('standard');
        1;
    });

    $('#checkBoxStandard').click(function(e) {
        $('#checkBoxStandard').change();
        1;
    });
});
```

Comment: Now i have the "problem" that the "clickedFormBoxen" is called 2times in one click. 
Im Having the clickevent like you said with click&change.                                                          


function clickedFormBoxen(active){if(active == 'standard'){
$('#checkBoxStandard').prop("checked", !($('#checkBoxStandard').prop("checked")));

  if( $('#checkBoxStandard').is(":checked")){
   form = active;
  }else{
   form = null;
  }
 }
 
  console.log("mhh: "+form);

Comment: that's by design. One call to `clickedFormBoxen` reverts the checkbox toggle by user action, the second performs the change. setting the checkboxes programmatically causes only 1 call because there is no click event. you have (at least) 2 options to get rid of the extra call: preventing the automatic toggle after a user click (which i haven't yet found a method for) or triggering a click event instead of setting the checkbox state programmatically (which i don't know whether or not it fits into your overall application design).